# Only finding the next element

Tags: jquery

ok i have this jquery

```
    $('.make_request').ajaxForm(function() { 
// $('.band_notice').show();
$(this).parents('.accordionContent').find('.band_notice').show();
        });
```

I am using this [plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

I need to find the class element .band_notice that is in the form clicked

here is my html

```
    <div class="accordionContent">
<form action="/make_requests" class="make_request" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>                                                      .......
            .......
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input id="make_requests" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add to Set" /></td><td><span class="band_notice">Set Added</span></td></tr>
                  </form>


    <div class="accordionContent">
<form action="/make_requests" class="make_request" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>                                                      .......
            .......
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input id="make_requests" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add to Set" /></td><td><span class="band_notice">Set Added</span></td></tr>
                  </form>
```

For some reason my jquery is a bit off bit this seems like it should be right

```
$(this).parents('.accordionContent').find('.band_notice').show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take out the [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) portion and use the fourth parameter for the form, like this:

```
$('.make_request').ajaxForm(function(response, status, xhr, form) { 
  form.find('.band_notice').show();
});
```

[From the docs](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object), here are the parameters for your `success` method:

1. responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
2. statusText
3. xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
4. jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)

Comment: that actually didnt work...not sure why not...maybe this plugin is altering this

Comment: i did console.log(this) and got Object { url="/make_requests", more...}

Comment: @Matt - Ah, one sec, checking the parameters

Comment: @Matt - I updated the answer on how to do this, since `this` refers to the ajax object itself (and there's no way to provide a `context` option the way you're using it.  Using the fourth parameter which is a jQuery object representing the `<form>` is easy enough though.